# How to pass a constant into the Foreign Key attribute?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I have a model with a composite Key and a composite Foreign Key. Is it possible to pass a constant into the Foreign Key annotation, rather than a column name?

**Current Model:**

```
[Table("PBDS.INTERACTIONS")]
public partial class Interaction
{
    // NOTE: The primary key for the INTERACTIONS table is a composite key
    //       consisting of:
    //           - ACCOUNT_ID
    //           - CONTACT_DATE
    //           - CONTACT_SEQ
    //           - PAGE

    [Key]
    [Column("ACCOUNT_ID", Order = 0)]
    public int ACCOUNT_ID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("CONTACT_DATE", Order = 1)]
    public DateTime CONTACT_DATE { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("CONTACT_SEQ", Order = 2)]
    public int CONTACT_SEQ { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("PAGE", Order = 3)]
    public int PAGE { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ACCOUNT_ID,CONTACT_DATE,CONTACT_SEQ,PAGE,DATA_VALUE")]
    public InteractionData InteractionData { get; set; }

}
```

DATA_VALUE will always be a constant for my purposes. Ideally, I would hope I could have a Foreign Key setup like this:

**Desired Model:**

```
[Table("PBDS.INTERACTIONS")]
public partial class Interaction
{
    // NOTE: The primary key for the INTERACTIONS table is a composite key
    //       consisting of:
    //           - ACCOUNT_ID
    //           - CONTACT_DATE
    //           - CONTACT_SEQ
    //           - PAGE

    [Key]
    [Column("ACCOUNT_ID", Order = 0)]
    public int ACCOUNT_ID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("CONTACT_DATE", Order = 1)]
    public DateTime CONTACT_DATE { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("CONTACT_SEQ", Order = 2)]
    public int CONTACT_SEQ { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("PAGE", Order = 3)]
    public int PAGE { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ACCOUNT_ID,CONTACT_DATE,CONTACT_SEQ,PAGE,<Net_Cost_Constant_String>")]
    public InteractionData NetCost { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ACCOUNT_ID,CONTACT_DATE,CONTACT_SEQ,PAGE,<Airing_Phone_Constant_String>")]
    public InteractionData AiringPhone { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ACCOUNT_ID,CONTACT_DATE,CONTACT_SEQ,PAGE,<RepFirm_Constant_String>")]
    public InteractionData RepFirm { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ACCOUNT_ID,CONTACT_DATE,CONTACT_SEQ,PAGE,<Week_Day_Constant_String>")]
    public InteractionData WeekDay { get; set; }

}
```

Note that there are 130 unique values in *DATA_VALUE*, but I only want the 4 listed here.

Is this possible? Alternative methods are also welcome.

Comment: Since you don't mention your ORM, I assume you're using EF. Please edit the question if I'm wrong.

Comment: "DATA_VALUE will always be a constant for my purposes." Why do you need a foreign key relationship to a table where only one row is ever used?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto My question is targeted towards the ForeignKey annotation which has a different parameter structure than your proposed duplicate. It doesn't seem like a duplicate to me and that question's answers don't help me.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I agree it's odd, but I need to keep the Table attribute for code consistency and I don't have access to DATA_VALUE in my Interactions class. It doesn't let you declare variables unless they match up to a column in the Table. Probably a better way to handle this. If so, I'm open to suggestion.

Comment: @jpaugh Technically it would be a constant 4 separate times with 4 different constants. I don't have access to DATA_VALUE from my Interactions class (or any other table in the database for that matter) but I need to use it as part of a composite key to get single records from another table.